# Prevent or remove leaflet effect adding/removing layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Good afternoon everyone!

I´m trying to make a 360 degree viewer using leaflet. Everything works fine but transition on adding/removing layers. It means that i want no transitions on swapping. The only way I found to prevent this was by adding all tile layers together and playing with "bringToFront" and "bringToBack" methods, but I have to load 80 tile layers with different zoom levels, and it makes a very poor and slow viewer.

So, my question is: does anyone know how to keep only one tile layer in map, and add or remove previous/next layers preventing this transition effect, without adding all 80 layers?

My working code is:

```
    window.onload = init;

    var map = "";
    var oldSrc = "";
    var gui = "";
    var path = "";
    var imgcounter = 1;
    var extension = "_img/";
    var files = new Array(80);
    var layers = new Array(80);
    var activate = "";

    function init() {
        oldSrc = './360/TNFF_0PO6055M_001/TNFF_0PO6055M_001-001_img/';
        gui = oldSrc.indexOf("-");
        path = oldSrc.substr(0, gui + 1);

        getFiles();

        //SLIDER
        $(function() {
            $("#slider").slider({
                range : "min",
                value : 1,
                min : 1,
                max : 80,
                slide : function(event, ui) {

                    var photonumber = ui.value;

                    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
                        if (i == photonumber) {
                            layers[i].bringToFront();
                        } else {
                            layers[i].bringToBack();
                        }
                    }

                    imgcounter = ui.value;

                }
            });

        });

        //BUTTONS
        $('.custom_previous').bind('click', function(e) {
            rotateLeft();
        });

        $('.custom_play').bind('click', function(e) {
            play();
        });

        $('.custom_stop').bind('click', function(e) {
            stop();
        });

        $('.custom_next').bind('click', function(e) {
            rotateRight();
        });

        //LEAFLET
        map = L.map('image-map').setView([0, 0], 2);
        buildLayers();
        /*
         var southWest = map.getBounds().getSouthWest(),
         northEast = map.getBounds().getNorthEast(),
         bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
         map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
         */
    }

    //GET FOLDER FILES
    function getFiles() {
        oldSrc = './360/TNFF_0PO6055M_001/TNFF_0PO6055M_001-001_img/';
        gui = oldSrc.indexOf("-");
        path = oldSrc.substr(0, gui + 1);
        var zero = "0";
        var doubleZero = "00";

        for (var i = 1; i <= 80; i++) {
            if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
                files[i - 1] = path + doubleZero + String(i) + extension;
            } else {
                files[i - 1] = path + zero + String(i) + extension;
            }
        }
    }

    //BUILD TILE LAYERS
    function buildLayers() {
        for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
            layers[i] = L.tileLayer.zoomify(files[i], {
                width : 8688,
                height : 5792,
                minZoom : 1,
                maxZoom : 4,
                attribution : 'LBNV'
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    }

    //ROTATE LEFT
    function rotateLeft() {
        if (imgcounter >= 80) {
            imgcounter = 1;
        } else {
            imgcounter++;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
            if (i == imgcounter) {
                layers[i].bringToFront();
            } else {
                layers[i].bringToBack();
            }
        }
        $("#slider").slider('value', imgcounter);
    }

    //ROTATE RIGHT
    function rotateRight() {
        if (imgcounter <= 1) {
            imgcounter = 80;
        } else {
            imgcounter--;
        }

        for (var i = 1; i <= 80; i++) {
            if (i == imgcounter) {
                layers[i - 1].bringToFront();
            } else {
                layers[i - 1].bringToBack();
            }
        }
        $("#slider").slider('value', imgcounter);
    }

    //PLAY
    function play() {
        activate = setInterval(animate, 250);
    }

    //PLAY ANIMATION
    function animate() {
        if (imgcounter > 80) {
            imgcounter = 1;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
            if (i == imgcounter) {
                layers[i].bringToFront();
            } else {
                layers[i].bringToBack();
            }
        }
        imgcounter++;
        $("#slider").slider('value', imgcounter);
    }

    //STOP
    function stop() {
        clearInterval(activate);
    }
```

Thaks everyone for your time and your help!

UPDATE: I'm looking for something like this: http://bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/i18n/consulta/registro.cmd?id=17092

Answer (score 1):

leave a short timeout before actually removing other layer(s), because the new tiles will appear with a little delay and transition, even if they are correctly loaded already. you may also need to harden your "removeAllLayersExcept" function to cover the case where a more recent Tile Layer is loaded before a previous one. Otherwise the previous layer will make the new one be removed from map. But then you also need to handle the case when the user manually drags the cursor backwards.

Comment: I tried several ways before: leaving a timeout before removing previous layer after next one is added to map, and had same behaviour... updating layer´s url (setUrl) with similar result.., played with layers opacity (same result)...

Comment: I'm looking for something like this: http://bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/i18n/consulta/registro.cmd?id=17092

Comment: UPDATED IN 1st POST